# Finding the position of an item in another list from a number in a different list

Tags: python, list, element

Developing on my previous question I'm wondering whether there is a way to have an element in a list and find that position in another list and return what is in the position as a variable. for example:

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
list2 = ["0","hello","my","name","is","Daniel"]
```

if the user enters the number 14 the program will return "hello Daniel" in the sense that the computer reads 14 as 1 and 4 and finds the position in list as an example.

I've tired using `[list2.index(x) for x in list1]` hoping that it would work but I've been unable to change the code so it does work. is there a simple way to do it

Comment: Of course there's a way to do it. But you need to try.

Comment: Yes of course, you just need to turn `14` into individual digits and there are plenty of questions on that in SO.

Comment: What is `list1` for?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: `' '.join(list2[int(index)] for index in str(number))`

Comment: @AChanpion I forgot to mention that I already converted 14 into a list itself by doing `list(14)` sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: Numbers are not iterable, `list(14)` wont work but `list('14')` will.

Comment: @SatishGarg my bad. then is there a way to convert 14 into two separate integer in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
input_num = 123
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] # if list1 is not dervied from input number
list2 = ["0", "hello", "my", "name", "is", "Daniel"]
print(' '.join([list2[list1.index(int(ind))] for ind in str(input_num)]))
```

This will result in :

```
hello my name
```

Also, i would suggest you to look at the https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html and trying things out to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will solve your problem:
for x in list1:
   print list2[x]

Is it that what you were asking ?